# How to work out frequency of certain key's value in an array of hashes?

Tags: ruby

I have an array of hashes. Each hash has an `uses` key. Multiple hashes can share the same `uses` value.

```
[{uses => 0},{uses => 1},{uses => 2},{uses => 1},{uses => 0},{uses => 1},{uses => 3}]
```

How can I generate an array of the most frequent `uses` values, in a descending order?

```
[1,0,2,3]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referencing [this discussion of frequency of items in a list](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/219236), we can easily modify this for your task.

```
> unsorted = [{:uses=>0}, {:uses=>1}, {:uses=>2}, {:uses=>1}, {:uses=>0}, {:uses=>1}, {:uses=>3}].map{|h| h[:uses]}
> sorted = unsorted.uniq.sort_by{|u| unsorted.grep(u).size}.reverse
 => [1, 0, 2, 3]
```

Comment: ok (for being so compact) for small inputs, but the algorithm looks very inefficient. And it was my understanding that the input was just an example and the hashes had more info (so `uniq` won't do)

Comment: I agree that a more interesting question would be, "What is the most efficient way of doing this?"

Answer (score 1):

```
hs.inject({}) do |histogram, h|
  histogram.merge(h[:uses] => (histogram[h[:uses]] || 0) + 1)
end.sort_by { |k, v| -v }.map { |k, v| k }
# => [1, 0, 2, 3]
```

I always recommend to use Facets, though:

http://rubyworks.github.com/facets/doc/api/core/Enumerable.html

```
hs.frequency.sort_by { |k, v| -v }.map { |k, v| k }
# => [1, 0, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one pass solution:

```
a = [{:uses => 0},{:uses => 1},{:uses => 2},{:uses => 1},{:uses => 0},
  {:uses => 1},{:uses => 3}]

# A hash with the frequency count is formed in one iteration of the array
# followed by the reverse sort and extraction

a.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |h, v| h[v[:uses]] += 1;h}.
  sort{|x, y| x <=> y}.map{|kv| kv[0]}
```